# Reading a fortigate configuration file with Python

Tags: python, list, configparser

Appologies for the really long drawn out question.

I am trying to read in a config file and get a list of rules out.
I have tried to use ConfigParser to do this but it is not a standard config file.
The file contains no section header and no token.

i.e.

> config section a 
>    set something to something else
>    config subsection a
>    set this to that
>    next 
>    end
>
> config firewall policy 
>    edit 76 
>    set srcintf "There" 
>    set dstintf "Here" 
>    set srcaddr "all"  
>    set dstaddr "all"  
>    set action accept  
>    set schedule "always" 
>    set service "TCP_5600" 
>    next 
>    edit 77 
>    set srcintf "here" 
>    set dstintf "there" 
>    set srcaddr "all" 
>    set dstaddr "all" 
>    set action accept 
>    set schedule "always" 
>    set service "PING" 
>    next  
>    end

As I couldn't work out how to get ConfigParser to work I thought I would try to iterate through the file, unfortunately I don't have much programming skill so I have got stuck.
I really think I am making this more complicated than it should be. 
Here's the code I have written;

```
class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config_section = ""
        self.config_header = ""
        self.section_list = []
        self.header_list = []

    def parse_config(self, fields): # Create a new section
        new_list = []
        self.config_section = " ".join(fields)
        new_list.append(self.config_section)

        if self.section_list: # Create a sub section
            self.section_list[-1].append(new_list)
        else: self.section_list.append(new_list)

    def parse_edit(self, line): # Create a new header
        self.config_header = line[0]
        self.header_list.append(self.config_header)

        self.section_list[-1].append(self.header_list)  

    def parse_set(self, line): # Key and values
        key_value = {}

        key = line[0]
        values = line[1:]
        key_value[key] = values

        if self.header_list:
            self.header_list.append(key_value)
        else: self.section_list[-1].append(key_value)

    def parse_next(self, line): # Close the header
        self.config_header = []

    def parse_end(self, line): # Close the section
        self.config_section = []

    def parse_file(self, path):
        with open(path) as f:
            for line in f:

                # Clean up the fields and remove unused lines.            
                fields = line.replace('"', '').strip().split(" ")

                if fields[0] == "set":
                    pass
                elif fields[0] == "end":
                    pass
                elif fields[0] == "edit":
                    pass
                elif fields[0] == "config":
                    pass
                elif fields[0] == "next":
                    pass
                else: continue

                # fetch and call method.
                method = fields[0]
                parse_method = "parse_" + method

                getattr(Parser, parse_method)(self, fields[1:])
                return self.section_list

config = Parser().parse_file('test_config.txt')

print config
```

The output I am looking for is something like the following;

> [['section a', {'something': 'to something else'}, ['subsection a', {'this': 'to that'}]],['firewall policy',['76',{'srcintf':'There'}, {'dstintf':'Here'}{etc.}{etc.}]]]

and this is what I get

> [['section a']]

**EDIT**

I have changed the above to reflect where I am currently at.
I am still having issues getting the output I expect. I just can't seem to get the list right.

Comment: The standard Python style, as recommended in PEP 8, is to use lowercase variable names with underscores as the word separator.

Comment: When writing a parser, the `shlex` module may well be helpful for dealing with quotes properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Parser(object):

     def __init__(self):
         self.my_section = 0
         self.flag_section = False
         # ...

    def parse_config(self, fields):
         self.my_section += 1
         # go on with fields
         # ...
         self.flag_section = True

     def parse_edit(self, line):
         ...

     def parse_set(self, line):
         ...

     def parse_end(self, line):
         ...

     def parse_file(self, path):
         with open(path) as f:
              for line in f:
                  fields = f.strip().split(" ")

                  method = fields[0]
                  # fetch and call method
                  getattr(Parser, "parse_" + method)(self, fields[1:])
```

Comment: Please, use `parse_config` etc. rather than `parseConfig`. It's the standard Python style. As this has been marked as community wiki, I'll "correct" it.

Comment: @Chris I wasn't aware of the standards for Python, my only programming knowledge comes from VB a very long time ago. I have acquainted myself with PEP and will try to make sure I follow it. Thanks.

Comment: I knew I could do this as an object but I just couldn't get my head around it. The use of getattr() and method is genius. This is exactly what I was looking for thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I post my answer for people who first come here from Google when trying to parse Fortigate configuration file !
I rewrote what I found here based on my own needs and it works great.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint
import sys

f = lambda: defaultdict(f)

def getFromDict(dataDict, mapList):
    return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], mapList, dataDict)

def setInDict(dataDict, mapList, value):
    getFromDict(dataDict, mapList[:-1])[mapList[-1]] = value    

class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.config_header = []
        self.section_dict = defaultdict(f)     

    def parse_config(self, fields): # Create a new section
        self.config_header.append(" ".join(fields))

    def parse_edit(self, line): # Create a new header
        self.config_header.append(line[0])

    def parse_set(self, line): # Key and values
        key = line[0]
        values = " ".join(line[1:])
        headers= self.config_header+[key]
        setInDict(self.section_dict,headers,values)

    def parse_next(self, line): # Close the header
        self.config_header.pop()

    def parse_end(self, line): # Close the section
        self.config_header.pop()

    def parse_file(self, path):          
        with open(path) as f:
            gen_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f if line.strip())
            for line in gen_lines:
               # pprint(dict(self.section_dict))
                # Clean up the fields and remove unused lines.            
                fields = line.replace('"', '').strip().split(" ")

                valid_fields= ["set","end","edit","config","next"]
                if fields[0] in valid_fields:
                    method = fields[0]
                    # fetch and call method
                    getattr(Parser, "parse_" + method)(self, fields[1:])

        return self.section_dict

config = Parser().parse_file('FGT02_20130308.conf')

print config["system admin"]["admin"]["dashboard-tabs"]["1"]["name"]
print config["firewall address"]["ftp.fr.debian.org"]["type"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this can help you too, but it did for me : http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples

Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in a simpler way:

```
flagSection = False
flagSub = False

mySection = 0
mySubsection = 0
myItem = 0

with open('d:/config.txt', 'r') as f:
    gen_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f if line.strip())

    for line in gen_lines:

            if line[0:7]=='config ':
                mySection = mySection + 1
                newLine = line[7:]
                # Create a new section
                # Mark section as open
                flagSection == True

            elif line[0:5]=='edit '):
                mySubsection = mySubsection + 1
                newLine = line[5:]
                # Create a new sub-section
                # Mark subsection as open
                flagSub == true

            elif line[0:4]=='set '):
                myItem = myItem + 1
                name, value = x.split(' ',2)[1:]
                # Add to whatever is open

            elif line=='end':
                # If subsection = open then close and goto end
                if flagSub:
                # Or if section = open then close and goto end
                elif flagSection:
                # :End
                continue
```

The instruction `gen_lines = (line.rstrip() for line in f if line.strip())`
 creates a generator of not empty lines (thanks to the test `if line.strip()`) without newline and without blanks at the right (thanks to `line.rstrip()`)

.

If I would know more about the operations you want to perform with name,value and in the section opened with `if line=='end'` , I could propose a code using regexes.

### Edit

```
from time import clock

n = 1000000

print 'Measuring times with clock()'

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    x = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')
print clock()-te,
print "\tx = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')"


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    x = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')
print clock()-te,
print "\tx = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')"



print '\nMeasuring times with timeit module'

import timeit

ti = timeit.repeat("x = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')",repeat=10,number = n)
print min(ti),
print "\tx = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')"

to = timeit.repeat("x = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')",repeat=10,number = n)
print min(to),
print "\tx = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')"
```

result:

```
Measuring times with clock()
0.543445605517  x = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')
1.08590449345   x = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')

Measuring times with timeit module
0.294152748464  x = ('abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end')
0.901923289133  x = 'abcdfafdf'.startswith('end')
```

Is the fact the times are smaller with **timieit** than with **clock()**  due to the fact that the GC is unplugged when the program is run ? Anyway, with either **clock()** or **timeit** module , executing **startswith()** takes more time than slicing.

Comment: line.startswith("set ") ... is nicer than giving the slice explicitly.

Comment: startswith() and endswith() are slower , the reason I prefer slicing. But I admit they give more readibility to the code; and also, they dont produce an error if the tested string is **""** , which is not a problem in my code because **gen_lines** delivers not-empty lines

Comment: >python -m timeit "'abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end';"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.261 usec per loop


>python -m timeit '"abcdfafdf".startswith("end");'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0381 usec per loop

Comment: @rocksportrocker Strange. I tested and I obtained what I said: see the edit in my answer.  By the way there are 6 zeros in **>python -m timeit "'abcdfafdf'[:3] == 'end';" 1000000 loops**, and there are 7 zeros in **>python -m timeit '"abcdfafdf".startswith("end");' 10000000 loops**